# Does publishing to a virtual folder within azure app service auto-swap?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

As I understand staging swap is only for the whole app-service, which is good enough, however I now like using the auto-swap feature for the main site, but I certainly don't want that to trigger when I publish to a virtual folder sub-site because that would put the old main site back live.

Hope default behavior would NOT be so silly to swap on virtual folders, but Cannot find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know, if a deployment slot is configured for Auto Swap into production, every time we push the code update to that slot, App Service will automatically swap the app into production after it has already warmed up in the slot. For detailed information, please check [**Auto Swap**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#configure-auto-swap) section in article.

Comment: This was my understanding also, but that article does not explicitly say such. It does not say anything about virtual folders/applications.

Comment: When Auto Swap is turned on, pushing updates to main site or virtual applications/directories in that slot would trigger a swap. If you worry the code updates may have unexpected effect on production slot, you could create a dev slot and do swap between dev slot and staging slot instead of swapping into production slot directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior is that any deployment will trigger a swap if you have auto-swap enabled.